# VSCode Extension: How to set value?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I read through the API doc and understand how to get values, but cannot get well how to set a value.

For example, I wanted to change active line (cursor line) so tried to update the value of `editor.selection.active` as follows.

```
// get the current value
editor.selection.active
V {_line: 12, _character: 0}

// I tried to update the value
editor.selection.active.line = 3
3

// I was expecting this an updated value but unchanged
editor.selection.active
V {_line: 12, _character: 0}
```

But as the comments above, it doesn't update the value, doesn't change the active line position. So How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: for selection update: create a new arrays with the selections you want and assign this array to `editor.selections`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the `editor.selections` property with your new selection:

```js
const newStartPosition = new vscode.Position(3, 0);
const newEndPosition = new vscode.Position(yourLine, yourCharacter);
const newSelections = [new vscode.Selection(newStartPosition, newEndPosition )];


editor.selections = newSelections;
```